# Django - Can CreateView additionally create an entry in another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Can the CreateView be extendet so that after the entry in the Order-Model is created, an additional entry in the Shipping-Model is created automatically. In the Shipping-Model a new id (UUID) should be assigned and the created order should be entered as ForeignKey.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="order",
    )
    …

class Shipping(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="shipping",
    )
    …

class Order_CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'client',
            …,
            )

class OrderCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    template_name = "order/order_create.html"
    form_class = Order_CreateForm
```

I was not sure how to create a corresponding entry in the Shipping-Model or how and where to enter the required code.

Best regards!
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Try to Google your question, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here and there are also answers here.
You have different ways to create Shipping-Model automatically.
if you want to craete it inside `OrderCreateView`, you can override `form_valid()` method.
In your case it's be like that:

```py
def form_valid(self, form): 
     response = super().form_valid(form) #first saves object
     obj = Shipping.objects.create(order=self.object)
     return response
```